# Convert the group by pandas dataframe in proper way

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pivot-table

I have dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd

emp_df = pd.DataFrame({'empid':[101,101,101,101,102,102],
                   'salary':[1000,1000,1500,2000,3000,4000],
                   'month':['Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Apr','May'],
                   'year':[2020,2020,2021,2021,2019,2021]})
emp_df
```

Original data looks like :

[image]

I am trying to get the output like this :

[image]

What I got till now was :

**Method -1 :**

```
t1 = emp_df.groupby(["empid", "year"]).agg(
    Total_salary=("salary", "sum")
).reset_index()
t1
t1.pivot_table(columns='year')
```

[image]

**Method -2 :**

```
t3 = emp_df.groupby(['empid','year']).agg('salary').sum('total').reset_index()
t4 = gp.pivot_table(columns=['empid','year'])
pd.DataFrame(t4.to_records())
```

[image]

basically I want to get two type of outputs here -

1. One as shown above ,its sum(salary) per empid w.r.t year wise(JAN-DEC).
2. Other would be calculating the sum(salary) per empid w.r.t financial year wise(APR-MAR).

How can I represent the data properly at least for the first step? Both this steps were easy in PowerBI, but I want to same logic here on notebooks to represent outputs correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with aggrgate function `sum`:

```
df = emp_df.pivot_table(index='empid',
                        columns='year', 
                        values='salary', 
                        aggfunc='sum', 
                        fill_value=0)
print (df)
year   2019  2020  2021
empid                  
101       0  2000  3500
102    3000     0  4000
```

For second first create new column for financial year and pass to `pivot_table`:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(emp_df['year'].astype(str)+emp_df['month'], format='%Y%b')

emp_df['financial_year'] = np.where(d.dt.month > 3,  d.dt.year, d.dt.year-1)
df2 = emp_df.pivot_table(index='empid',
                        columns='financial_year', 
                        values='salary', 
                        aggfunc='sum', 
                        fill_value=0)
print (df2)

financial_year  2019  2021
empid                     
101             2000  3500
102             3000  4000
```